# Python how to transform the below into a nice list of json object (like i would get from an API)

Tags: json, python-3.x, api

This is the format of data i have:

```
('Domain Name,Start Date,End Date,Attributed To,Tags\r\n'
 'domain.com,2011-01-01,Active,Company A SA,\r\n'
 'domain.com,2011-01-01,Active,Company A SA,\r\n'
 'domain.com,2011-01-01,Active,Company A SA,\r\n'
 'domain.com,2011-01-01,Active,Company A SA,\r\n'
'Domain Name,Start Date,End Date,Attributed To,Tags\r\n'
 'domain.com,2011-01-01,Active,Company A SA,\r\n')
```

How can i transform that data above into a nice list of json object? like so:

```
[
{'Domain Name': 'domain.com',
 'Start Date': '2011-01-01',
 'End Date': 'Active',
 'Attributed To': 'Company A SA',
 'Tags': 'None'}
{'Domain Name': 'domain.com',
 'Start Date': '2011-01-01',
 'End Date': 'Active',
 'Attributed To': 'Company A SA',
 'Tags': 'None'}
{'Domain Name': 'domain.com',
 'Start Date': '2011-01-01',
 'End Date': 'Active',
 'Attributed To': 'Company A SA',
 'Tags': 'None'}
{'Domain Name': 'domain.com',
 'Start Date': '2011-01-01',
 'End Date': 'Active',
 'Attributed To': 'Company A SA',
 'Tags': 'None'}]
```

So far have tried json.dumps, json.loads and even csv.dictreader but i cant seem to figure it out, apologies if beginner question

Comment: What is your input format? a list? are there some commas missing?

Comment: thanks for reply @JANO, this is from an API call that i have to ".text" and the response looks exactly like that, which according to my limited python knowledge is a Tuple?

Comment: That is not JSON. You want a list of dicts

Comment: And that isn't a tuple. That is just a string presumably, otherwise it isn't a valid python data structure. You really must specify these things precisely

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to create a pandas [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) from your input string. This dataframe can then be easily converted to a JSON string. Following code is needed to create the dataframe:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# Create your data frame
input_tuple = ('Domain Name,Start Date,End Date,Attributed To,Tags\r\n'
 'domain.com,2011-01-01,Active,Company A SA,\r\n'
 'domain.com,2011-01-01,Active,Company A SA,\r\n'
 'domain.com,2011-01-01,Active,Company A SA,\r\n'
 'domain.com,2011-01-01,Active,Company A SA,\r\n'
 'domain.com,2011-01-01,Active,Company A SA,\r\n')

# Create a continous string
input_str = ''.join(input_list)

# Create a dataframe from the string
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input_str), sep=',')
```

This dataframe looks then like this:

```
  Domain Name  Start Date End Date Attributed To  Tags
0  domain.com  2011-01-01   Active  Company A SA   NaN
1  domain.com  2011-01-01   Active  Company A SA   NaN
2  domain.com  2011-01-01   Active  Company A SA   NaN
3  domain.com  2011-01-01   Active  Company A SA   NaN
4  domain.com  2011-01-01   Active  Company A SA   NaN
```

The function [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) can then be used to create your desired JSON string:

```
# Convert dataframe to json
result = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

The final result looks like this:

```
[{"Domain Name":"domain.com","Start Date":"2011-01-01","End Date":"Active","Attributed To":"Company A SA","Tags":null},{"Domain Name":"domain.com","Start Date":"2011-01-01","End Date":"Active","Attributed To":"Company A SA","Tags":null},{"Domain Name":"domain.com","Start Date":"2011-01-01","End Date":"Active","Attributed To":"Company A SA","Tags":null},{"Domain Name":"domain.com","Start Date":"2011-01-01","End Date":"Active","Attributed To":"Company A SA","Tags":null},{"Domain Name":"domain.com","Start Date":"2011-01-01","End Date":"Active","Attributed To":"Company A SA","Tags":null}]
```

Comment: This is great and really got me close! i will keep working on it but i think this is the most elegant solution i found so far, thank you

Comment: Glad I could help! pandas is a great tool to use for almost any problem regarding datasets.